# Writing delay time of GIF file in matlab

Tags: matlab, gif

I want to re-write GIF file with the equal delay time with the original file. This is the example image :

[image: input]

This is my code, but the output has slower delay than the original. Is there a way to make it equals?

```
[I map]=imread('a.gif');
delay=0.1;
frame=size(I,4);
loops=65535;
for i = 1:frame
    if i==1
        imwrite(I(:,:,:,i),map,'b.gif','gif','LoopCount',loops, 'DelayTime', delay); %save file output
    else
        imwrite(I(:,:,:,i),'b.gif','gif','WriteMode', 'append'); %save file output
    end
end
```

The result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
[I map]=imread('a.gif');
delay=0.03;
frame=size(I,4);
for i = 1:frame
    if i==1
        imwrite(I(:,:,:,i),map,'b.gif','gif', 'DelayTime', delay,'LoopCount',inf); %save file output
    else
        imwrite(I(:,:,:,i),'b.gif','gif','WriteMode', 'append', 'DelayTime', delay); %save file output
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of Matlab, `imread` also inputs the frame index:

```matlab
filename = 'a.gif';
output = 'b.gif';
delay= 0.03;

frames = numel(imfinfo(filename));
for i = 1:frames
    disp("Working on frame " + i + " out of " + frames)

    [I, map] = imread(filename, i);

    if i==1
        imwrite(I,map, output, 'gif', 'DelayTime', delay,'LoopCount',inf); %save file output
    else
        imwrite(I, output, 'gif','WriteMode', 'append', 'DelayTime', delay); %save file output
    end
end
```